# How keycloak sets up user information from an external identity provider

Tags: azure-active-directory, keycloak

During use, I found that **keycloak** automatically registers a new user in the local database after obtaining the user information of the external identity provider(**Azure AD**).Can the user's username be consistent with the user information of the external identity provider(**Azure AD**) in some way? For example, the **username** of the newly registered user is automatically set to the **user mailbox** of the external identity provider(**Azure AD**)?

ps:keycloak 7.0.1 windows10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use identity privider mapper.

For email the mapper is of type Attribute Importer. Map the user attribute email to http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress.

For username the mapper is of type Username Template Importer. Map the user attribute username to ${ATTRIBUTE.http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/subjectname}.

For surname the mapper is of type Attribute Importer. Map the user attribute lastName to http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname.

For given name the mapper is of type Attribute Importer. Map the user attribute firstName to http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname.

Comment: I'm using SAML, it doesn't works for me :(